# Configure Thymeleaf in a multi-module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, module, properties, thymeleaf

My project structure, so the root has 2 modules declared in pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>svpm-service</module>
    <module>svpm-web</module>
</modules>

<groupId>md.svpm</groupId>
<artifactId>svpm</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>svpm</name>
```

[image]

How is this that Thymeleaf won't get the path and configs to my templates folder? I have a multi-module project where the frontend is a separate module, trying to get that working at least from ***WebConfig.java*** that is placed in root, but even that it won't get the path.

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/"); // < - here the code
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

```
Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
```

**First case:** even if I change the path in ***WebConfig.java*** to another one - it still says

*Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)*

**Second case:** if I add the lines below to all of the **application.properties** it considers only the one from **svpm-service** and still nothing

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Uday yes, I did

Comment: So can you answer your question with the solution?

Comment: @Uday see below, if you have other issues, let me know, I'll try to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in specifying the modules and the way Spring Boot reads configurations for specific module, it is easy to understand that:

In root pom.xml I have the followinf declaration of 3 modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>application</module>
    <module>frontend</module>
    <module>service</module>
</modules>
```

In application's pom.xml I have only the dependency for **service** module

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>md.svpm</groupId>
     <artifactId>service</artifactId>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
     <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Next, in *service* I have the **frontend** dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>md.svpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

So in that way, the **service** knows about **frontend** and the application knows about **service**, it is a chain of well designed module application. It will not work other way.